# How to implement date range selection or muti date selection feature in single kendo calendar?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

Is it possible to have date range selection and multi date selection feature using single kendo calendar instance?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36722158/single-calendar-date-range-picker - still no answer. All they present is using 2 datepickers

Answer (score 0):

By default kendo dont have that feature. But you can vote for it here:

http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/127393-telerik-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/4122749-add-range-select-to-datepicker

Also here you can find couple custom solutions:

[Kendo UI Calendar Multiselection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25903960/kendo-ui-calendar-multiselection)